# using clang compile ffmpeg with too much warning on osx

Tags: ios, macos, ffmpeg, clang

I use clang to compile ffmpeg, It reports too much warn

```
./libavutil/arm/intmath.h:102:40: warning: value size does not match register size specified by the constraint and modifier
      [-Wasm-operand-widths]
./libavutil/arm/intmath.h:102:40: warning: value size does not match register size specified by the constraint and modifier
      [-Wasm-operand-widths]
```

and finally stop with error

```
libavcodec/arm/mlpdsp_armv5te.S:5180:9: error: unknown directive
        .hword (75f - 0b) / 2
        ^
libavcodec/arm/mlpdsp_armv5te.S:5182:9: error: unknown directive
        .hword (76f - 0b) / 2
        ^
libavcodec/arm/mlpdsp_armv5te.S:5184:9: error: unknown directive
        .hword (77f - 0b) / 2
        ^
libavcodec/arm/mlpdsp_armv5te.S:5186:9: error: unknown directive
        .hword (78f - 0b) / 2
        ^
libavcodec/arm/mlpdsp_armv5te.S:5648:9: error: unknown directive
```

Is there anyone met the same problem?

Comment: You may have luck with `-no-integrated-as`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118887/how-to-switch-off-llvms-integrated-assembler