# Produce both assembly and object file with gcc/clang: Possible? How?

Tags: gcc, compilation, clang, disassembly, object-files

Is it possible to produce both the object file and the source file in once command with gcc/g++/clang/clang++ ? How?

I need to pass a lot of other options, so I would like to avoid duplicating them in 2 separate commands:

```
gcc -S test.cc # produce assembly
gcc -c test.cc # produce object file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give the `-save-temps` option to gcc: it will leave all the temporary files (including the `.s` files) in the current directory (works also with `clang`):

```
gcc -c --save-temps test.cc
```

or use the `-Wa,-aln=test.s` option:

```
gcc -c -Wa,-aln=test.s test.c
```

From `gcc` documentation:

> `-Wa,option`
>
> Pass `option` as an option to the assembler. If option contains commas, it is split into multiple options at the commas.

From `as` documentation:

> `-a[cdghlmns]` Turn on listings, in any of a variety of ways:
>
> - `-al` include assembly
> - `-an` omit forms processing
>
> [...]
>
> You may combine these options; for example, use `-aln` for assembly listing without forms processing.

Clang has an integrated assembler that should be switched off ([How to switch off LLVM's integrated assembler?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11118887/3235496)):

```
clang++ -c -no-integrated-as -Wa,-aln=test.s test.c
```

Comment: It seems that `clang -c --save-temps test.cc` uses a different assembler than just `clang -S` or `clang -c`. And that assembler gives an error message on a feature being added to clang... Neither `clang -S` nor `clang -c` produce that error. So I don't know whether my modification is wrong or some more tweaks to the environment are needed. I'm on Windows, cross-compiling to ARM-Linux.