# Which assembler does clang use?

Tags: clang

I am not clear on the assembler used by clang. AFAIK native aka GNU assembler and linker is used (provided along with gcc).

```
clang -v main.c
clang version 3.4.2
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.5
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.5.3
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.3
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.5
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.5.3
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.3
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.5
 "/usr/bin/clang-3.4" -cc1 -triple x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -main-file-name main.c -mrelocation-model static -mdisable-fp-elim -fmath-errno -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -munwind-tables -target-cpu x86-64 -v -resource-dir /usr/bin/../lib/clang/3.4.2 -internal-isystem /usr/local/include -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/clang/3.4.2/include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -internal-externc-isystem /include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include -fdebug-compilation-dir /home/shrkamat/test/hello-c -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 230 -mstackrealign -fobjc-runtime=gcc -fdiagnostics-show-option -vectorize-slp -o /tmp/main-18929a.o -x c main.c
clang -cc1 version 3.4.2 based upon LLVM 3.4.2 default target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
ignoring nonexistent directory "/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/bin/../lib/clang/3.4.2/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
 "/usr/bin/ld" -z relro --hash-style=gnu --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o a.out /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.5/crtbegin.o -L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.5 -L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.5/../../.. -L/lib -L/usr/lib /tmp/main-18929a.o -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.5/crtend.o /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
```

I do see llvm-as too, not very clear if it is used.

```
which llvm-as
/usr/bin/llvm-as
root@e2cccbdeac09# llvm-as --version
LLVM (http://llvm.org/):
  LLVM version 3.4.2
  Optimized build.
  Built Aug  8 2019 (08:55:24).
  Default target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  Host CPU: core-avx-i
```

I did try to poke around system calls with strace, to check if there is any exec called for any of the assemblers, but no luck

```
grep -r exec trace.601*
trace.6016:execve("/usr/bin/clang", ["clang", "-v", "main.c"], [/* 12 vars */]) = 0
trace.6017:execve("/usr/bin/clang-3.4", ["/usr/bin/clang-3.4", "-cc1", "-triple", "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu", "-emit-obj", "-mrelax-all", "-disable-free", "-disable-llvm-verifier", "-main-file-name", "main.c", "-mrelocation-model", "static", "-mdisable-fp-elim", "-fmath-errno", "-masm-verbose", "-mconstructor-aliases", ...], [/* 12 vars */]) = 0
trace.6018:execve("/usr/bin/ld", ["/usr/bin/ld", "-z", "relro", "--hash-style=gnu", "--build-id", "--eh-frame-hdr", "-m", "elf_x86_64", "-dynamic-linker", "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2", "-o", "a.out", "/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux"..., "/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux"..., "/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux"..., "-L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-lin"..., ...], [/* 12 vars */]) = 0
```

Can I use GNU assembler (/usr/bin/as) with clang ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LLVM has its own assembler called Integrated Assembler. It consists of several libraries and doesn't have a user-facing frontend (well, there is `llvm-mc`, but it isn't really a replacement for `as`). The `llc` utility can invoke Integrated Assembler when passed `-filetype=obj` option. This is also the reason you don't see any assembler program invocation when tracing `execve` call.

Clang has `-no-integrated-as` flag to turn the LLVM assembler off.

Comment: Awesome, this works. Is there any way to make -no-integrated-as default ?

Comment: Either patch Clang source or use env vars: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11119528/637669